Bounding proofs of transfinite induction
Let $\phi$ be a "reasonable" formula in the language of first-order arithmetic expressing some amount of transfinite induction along a given (index for a) computable linear order; my default choice here is $\Sigma_1$-transfinite recursion, but I'm happy to tweak it if a different definition would result in an easier question.
Let $\mathsf{PA}$ be the usual first-order Peano arithmetic, and let $\mathsf{PA}_\omega$ be its cut-free infinitary analogue.

EDIT: As Anupam Das points out below, the full $\omega$-rule is far too strong for this question to be interesting. There are many weakenings of the $\omega$-rule studied in the literature, and I'm not sure which is appropriate. Here's one which I think de-trivializes the question, although I could be wrong and I'm separately happy for it to be replaced by a different weakening: we restrict attention to deductions which are computable as well-founded labelled trees and have some computable code which $\mathsf{PA}$ proves defines an appropriate tree.

Given an ordinal $\alpha$, let $P(\alpha)$ be the smallest rank of any $\mathsf{PA}_\omega$-deduction of $\varphi(e)$ for any index $e$ for a computable copy of $\alpha$.
My main question is:

What is $P$, explicitly?

However, a related question is whether we can compute $P$, or at least bound $P$ nontrivially, in a direct way:

Can we give an upper bound for $P(\alpha)$ in terms of $\alpha$ (and strictly below $\omega_1^\text{CK}$) without appealing to the second incompleteness theorem?

The motivation for this latter question is the broader question of whether Gentzen's theorem — that every $\mathsf{PA}$-proof corresponds to a $\mathsf{PA}_\omega$-proof with rank $<\epsilon_0$ — can yield Godel's first incompleteness theorem (for $\mathsf{PA}$ specifically) as a corollary in a non-circular way. The usual proof of this is via the second incompleteness theorem, but a positive answer to my second question would yield a specific $e$ such that $\mathsf{PA}\nvdash\varphi(e)$ without appealing to Godel along the way. (Put another way, I'm asking whether an old answer to another question of mine can be patched.)

If you have no further requirements on $P$ then why is it not just bounded above by $\omega$? Any true FO sentence $A$ should have a cut-free $\mathsf{PA}\omega$-proof of height bounded above by the logical complexity of $A$ (assuming axioms for all true closed atomic formulas) by mimicking the inductive definition of satisfaction in $\mathbb N$. Of course this argument is using an oracle for the standard model $\mathbb N$, which perhaps you want to avoid? (I am assuming here that, by $\mathsf{PA}\omega$ you mean $\mathsf{PA}$ but with the $\omega$-rule instead of induction axioms.)

Despite as Anupam pointed out the particular way you want to obtain examples of pressumably first-order independent sentences shouldn't work, the original Gentzen technique that actually was done via partial cut-elimination for finite proof-figures for $\mathsf{PA}$ actually gives such examples of independent sentences obtained without use of diagonalization. Namely $\Pi^0_2$-ordinal analysis of $\mathsf{PA}$ gives us the totality of $\mathsf{F}_{\varepsilon_0}$ as a $\mathsf{PA}$-unprovable $\Pi^0_2$ sentence.

@FedorPakhomov True, but doesn't that still invoke the second incompleteness theorem along the way (via if $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Tot(\mathsf{F}_{\epsilon_0}$ then $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Con(\mathsf{PA}$)?  Or am I misremebering?

@AnupamDas Good catch, I was sloppy! I had in mind a more restricted version of the $\omega$-rule, but forgot to add details when writing this question. I've edited, let me know if this seems to work.

If PA is complete then this weakened version is still bounded by $\omega$ (because first-order truth in $\mathbb{N}$ is decidable by searching for proofs in PA). Obviously it isn't (so in reality $P$ is (probably) nontrivial), but this seems like a problem if you want to derive the incompleteness of PA as a corollary.

I don't see why you would need to "unfold" proofs? I'm just pointing out that Anupam Das's construction becomes computable if PA is complete; the PA proofs are only used to decide the truth of arithmetic statements (to check if $\varphi$ is true, see which of $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ is provable). The underlying issue is that I can't see any way to get a useful bound on what's computable that doesn't immediately imply PA is incomplete.

@pastebee Ah, I see. Yes, that's a problem; I misunderstood (although I'm still interested in $P$'s actual behavior, relative to some nontrivializing choice of infinitary system).

@pastebee One possible response is to weaken the verifying theory, but I suspect that's not a fruitful road to go down.

@NoahSchweber No, $\Pi^0_2$-analysis of $\mathsf{PA}$ asserts that if a partial computable function is $\mathsf{PA}$-provably total then it is bounded by $\mathsf{F}\alpha$, for some $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$. Thus $\mathsf{PA}$ couldn't prove the totality of $F{\varepsilon_0}$ since then this function would be dominated by $\mathsf{F}_\alpha$, for some $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$, which could be directly proved not to be the case.

@FedorPakhomov Oh, cool! I'm not familiar with this - is there a good source on the $\Pi^0_2$ analysis?

@NoahSchweber There are bunch of presentations. The classical Gentzen style approach could be found for example in Takeuti "Proof Theory" book near in the of the chapter where he presents the consistency proof for $\mathsf{PA}$. A presentation based on operator controlled infinitary derivations can be found in Pohlers "The First Step into Impredicativity". I personally quite like the Herbrand Theorem based approach taken in J.Avigad's paper "Ordinal analysis without proofs".
